# subtract total counts from column in the previous row using SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code:

```
create table #attr( enroll_month datetime ,cncl_mth datetime,
mth int,
tot_orders int,tot_cancel int, active_count int, attr_rate int , retn_rate 
int
)

DECLARE
@enroll_mth datetime ,@cncl_mth datetime, @mth int ,
@tot_orders numeric, @tot_cancel numeric,
@attr_rate numeric(6,2), @retn_rate numeric(6,2),
@active_count int
DECLARE att_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT
d.Enroll_Month, d.cncl_mth, d.mth,
s.tot_orders, d.tot_cancel
FROM #Summary s with (nolock),
#Detail d with (nolock)
WHERE
s.Enroll_Month = d.Enroll_Month


OPEN att_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM att_cursor INTO @enroll_mth, @cncl_mth, @mth, @tot_orders, 
@tot_cancel

DECLARE
@old_enroll_mth datetime,
@old_cncl_mth datetime, @old_mth int, @month datetime ,
@intial varchar(1),
@old_active_cnt int, @old_tot_cancel int,
@old_retn_rate numeric(6,2), @old_attr_rate numeric(6,2),
@counter int

SELECT @old_enroll_mth = ''
SELECT @intial = 'Y'

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
IF (@old_enroll_mth <> @enroll_mth)
BEGIN
SELECT @active_count = @active_count - @tot_cancel
SELECT @intial = 'N'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT @active_count = @tot_orders - @tot_cancel
SELECT @intial = 'Y'
END

SELECT @retn_rate = (@active_count / @tot_orders) * 100
SELECT @attr_rate = 100 - @retn_rate

INSERT INTO #Attr (
 enroll_month, cncl_mth, mth, tot_orders, tot_cancel, 
active_count, attr_rate, retn_rate ) 
VALUES (
@enroll_mth, @cncl_mth, @mth, @tot_orders, @tot_cancel,
@active_count, @attr_rate, @retn_rate)





SELECT @old_enroll_mth = @enroll_mth
SELECT @old_mth = @mth
SELECT @old_retn_rate = @retn_rate
SELECT @old_attr_rate = @attr_rate
SELECT @old_active_cnt = @active_count
SELECT @old_cncl_mth = @cncl_mth
SELECT @old_tot_cancel = @tot_cancel

FETCH NEXT FROM att_cursor INTO @enroll_mth, @cncl_mth, @mth, @tot_orders, 
@tot_cancel
END

CLOSE att_cursor
DEALLOCATE att_cursor

select * from #attr
```

which is returning the below output.

```
enroll_month cncl_mth mth tot_orders tot_cancel active_count attr_rate retn_rate
01/01/17    01/01/17    1   390         160        230           41       58
01/01/17   02/01/17     2   390          26        364            6       93
01/01/17    03/01/17    3   390          23         594          -52      152
```

It is displaying the correct value for active count for mth=1 . Though for mth= 2 it should be (230-26=204) and for mth = 3 it should be (204-23 =181).

I have posted the two scripts to populate the  summary and detail tables that are used in my above script.

```
create table #summary
(
enroll_month datetime,
tot_orders int
)
go
insert into #summary(enroll_month, tot_orders)
values ('2017-01-01 00:00:00.000', 390)

insert into #summary(enroll_month, tot_orders )
values ('2017-02-01 00:00:00.000', 615)
go

drop table #Detail
go
create table #detail
(
enroll_month datetime,
cncl_mnth datetime,
mth int,
tot_cancel int
)
go
insert into #detail(enroll_month,cncl_mnth,mth,tot_cancel)
values ('2017-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2017-01-01 00:00:00.000', 1, 160)

insert into #detail(enroll_month,cncl_mnth,mth,tot_cancel )
values ('2017-01-01 00:00:00.000','2017-02-01 00:00:00.000', 2, 26)

insert into #detail(enroll_month,cncl_mnth,mth,tot_cancel)
values ('2017-01-01 00:00:00.000','2017-03-01 00:00:00.000', 3, 23)
go
```

Can you please help ?

Thanks,
Pam

Comment: Can you post the execution plan for the query (I've posted an example in my answer)? What version of SQL Server are you using? Is there an index on the column `[enroll_month]` in both tables? Can you post more example records so I can build the 250 records based on the pattern?

Answer (score 0):

is this helpful.?

```
    create table #summary ( enroll_month datetime, tot_orders int ) 
    insert into #summary(enroll_month, tot_orders) values ('2017-01-01 00:00:00.000', 390)
    insert into #summary(enroll_month, tot_orders ) values ('2017-02-01 00:00:00.000', 615) 


    create table #detail ( enroll_month datetime, cncl_mnth datetime, mth int, tot_cancel int ) 
    insert into #detail(enroll_month,cncl_mnth,mth,tot_cancel) values ('2017-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2017-01-01 00:00:00.000', 1, 160)
    insert into #detail(enroll_month,cncl_mnth,mth,tot_cancel ) values ('2017-01-01 00:00:00.000','2017-02-01 00:00:00.000', 2, 26)
    insert into #detail(enroll_month,cncl_mnth,mth,tot_cancel) values ('2017-01-01 00:00:00.000','2017-03-01 00:00:00.000', 3, 23)



    SELECT
    d.Enroll_Month, d.cncl_mnth, d.mth,
    s.tot_orders, d.tot_cancel
    into #tmp
    FROM #Summary s with (nolock),
    #Detail d with (nolock)
    WHERE
    s.Enroll_Month = d.Enroll_Month

    ;with cte
    As
    (
        Select Enroll_Month,cncl_mnth,mth,tot_orders,tot_cancel,
        tot_orders-tot_cancel as active_count,
        FLOOR(100-(CAST((tot_orders-tot_cancel) AS FLOAT)/CAST(tot_orders AS FLOAT))*100) as attr_rate, 
        FLOOR((CAST((tot_orders-tot_cancel) AS FLOAT)/CAST(tot_orders AS FLOAT))*100) as retn_rate
        from #tmp where mth=1

        Union All

        Select t.Enroll_Month,t.cncl_mnth,t.mth,t.tot_orders,t.tot_cancel,
        c.active_count-t.tot_cancel as active_count,
        FLOOR(100-(CAST((c.active_count-t.tot_cancel) AS FLOAT)/CAST(c.active_count AS FLOAT))*100) as attr_rate,   
        FLOOR((CAST((c.active_count-t.tot_cancel) AS FLOAT)/CAST(c.active_count AS FLOAT))*100) as retn_rate
        from #tmp t
        JOIN cte c on t.mth=c.mth+1
    )

    select * from cte

    Drop Table #tmp
    Drop table #summary
    Drop table #detail
```

output is:

```
Enroll_Month                    cncl_mnth          mth  tot_orders  tot_cancel  active_count    attr_rate   retn_rate
2017-01-01 00:00:00.000  2017-01-01 00:00:00.000    1      390         160         230               41          58
2017-01-01 00:00:00.000  2017-02-01 00:00:00.000    2      390         26          204               11          88
2017-01-01 00:00:00.000  2017-03-01 00:00:00.000    3      390         23          181               11          88
```

Comment: Thank you Sahi for the solution. I am using DataDetail table which contains 250 rows and has the same data elements and structure as the #detail table used in your code. When I replace #detail table with Datadetail table the query runs for a very long time . I had to stop it as it was running for 30 mins. Is there a way it can be optimized. Thanks! –

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [common table expression (CTE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and produce the total with a `SUM` and [OVER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause.

#### SQL:

```
WITH
summary
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( '01-Jan-2017', 390)
    , ( '01-Feb-2017', 615)
    ) tbl ([enroll_month], [tot_orders]) 
)
, 
details
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( '01-Jan-2017', '01-Jan-2017', 1, 160)
    , ( '01-Jan-2017', '01-Feb-2017', 2, 26)
    , ( '01-Jan-2017', '01-Mar-2017', 3, 23)
    ) tbl ([enroll_month], [cncl_mnth], [mth], [tot_cancel]) 
)
,
detail_active_count
AS
(
    SELECT
          d.[enroll_month]
        , d.[cncl_mnth]
        , s.[tot_orders]
        , d.[mth]
        , d.[tot_cancel]
        , [active_count] = s.[tot_orders] - SUM(d.[tot_cancel]) OVER (PARTITION BY d.[enroll_month] ORDER BY d.[mth]) 
    FROM 
        summary AS s
        INNER JOIN details as d ON d.[enroll_month] = s.[enroll_month]
)
SELECT
      c.* 
    , [attr_rate] = FLOOR(100 - (CAST((c.[active_count]) AS FLOAT) / CAST(c.[tot_orders] AS FLOAT)) * 100)
    , [retn_rate] = FLOOR((CAST((c.[active_count]) AS FLOAT) / CAST(c.[tot_orders] AS FLOAT)) * 100)
FROM 
    detail_active_count AS c
```

#### Results:

[image: screenshot]

#### Execution Plan Example:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you aduguid for the solution! I am using  DataDetail table which contains 250 rows and has the same data elements and structure as the #detail table used in your code. When I replace #detail table with Datadetail table the query runs for a very long time . I had to stop it as it was running for 30 mins. Is there a way it can be optimized. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in this part:

```
IF (@old_enroll_mth <> @enroll_mth)
BEGIN
SELECT @active_count = @active_count - @tot_cancel
SELECT @intial = 'N'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT @active_count = @tot_orders - @tot_cancel
SELECT @intial = 'Y'
END
```

you've flipped the logic you needed ;).. 
so you need it to be like this :

```
IF (@old_enroll_mth <> @enroll_mth)
BEGIN
    SELECT @active_count = @tot_orders - @tot_cancel
    SELECT @intial = 'Y'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT @active_count = @active_count - @tot_cancel
    SELECT @intial = 'N'
END
```

**UPDATED**

SAMPLE DATA

```
DECLARE @summary TABLE (enroll_month datetime,  tot_orders int)
DECLARE @detail TABLE (enroll_month datetime, cncl_mnth datetime, mth int, tot_cancel int)
DECLARE @attr TABLE (enroll_month datetime ,cncl_mth datetime, mth int, tot_orders int,tot_cancel int, active_count int, attr_rate int , retn_rate int)

insert into @summary(enroll_month, tot_orders) values 
('2017-01-01 00:00:00.000', 390),
('2017-02-01 00:00:00.000', 615)

insert into @detail(enroll_month,cncl_mnth,mth,tot_cancel) values 
('2017-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2017-01-01 00:00:00.000', 1, 160),
('2017-01-01 00:00:00.000','2017-02-01 00:00:00.000', 2, 26),
('2017-01-01 00:00:00.000','2017-03-01 00:00:00.000', 3, 23)
```

Using the above sample, and your `CURSOR` (with modifying the above logic - flipped) :

```
DECLARE
@enroll_mth datetime ,@cncl_mth datetime, @mth int ,
@tot_orders numeric, @tot_cancel numeric,
@attr_rate numeric(6,2), @retn_rate numeric(6,2),
@active_count int


DECLARE att_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
    d.Enroll_Month, d.cncl_mnth, d.mth,
    s.tot_orders, d.tot_cancel
    FROM @summary s, @Detail d
    WHERE
    s.Enroll_Month = d.Enroll_Month


OPEN att_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM att_cursor INTO @enroll_mth, @cncl_mth, @mth, @tot_orders, @tot_cancel

    DECLARE
    @old_enroll_mth datetime,
    @old_cncl_mth datetime, @old_mth int, @month datetime ,
    @intial varchar(1),
    @old_active_cnt int, @old_tot_cancel int,
    @old_retn_rate numeric(6,2), @old_attr_rate numeric(6,2),
    @counter int

SELECT @old_enroll_mth = ''
SELECT @intial = 'Y'

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
IF (@old_enroll_mth <> @enroll_mth)
BEGIN
    SELECT @active_count = @tot_orders - @tot_cancel
    SELECT @intial = 'Y'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT @active_count = @active_count - @tot_cancel
    SELECT @intial = 'N'
END

SELECT @retn_rate = (@active_count / @tot_orders) * 100
SELECT @attr_rate = 100 - @retn_rate

INSERT INTO @attr (enroll_month, cncl_mth, mth, tot_orders, tot_cancel, active_count, attr_rate, retn_rate ) 
           VALUES (@enroll_mth, @cncl_mth, @mth, @tot_orders, @tot_cancel, @active_count, @attr_rate, @retn_rate)

SELECT @old_enroll_mth = @enroll_mth
SELECT @old_mth = @mth
SELECT @old_retn_rate = @retn_rate
SELECT @old_attr_rate = @attr_rate
SELECT @old_active_cnt = @active_count
SELECT @old_cncl_mth = @cncl_mth
SELECT @old_tot_cancel = @tot_cancel

FETCH NEXT FROM att_cursor INTO @enroll_mth, @cncl_mth, @mth, @tot_orders, @tot_cancel
END

CLOSE att_cursor
DEALLOCATE att_cursor

SELECT * FROM @attr
```

If you're welling to take another method without `CURSOR` or `CTE`, then you can use this instead :

```
SELECT
    D.Enroll_Month
,   cncl_mnth
,   mth
,   tot_orders
,   tot_cancel
,   tot_orders - total_cancel active_count
,   100 - CAST(CAST((tot_orders - total_cancel) AS DECIMAL(18,2) ) / (tot_orders) * 100  AS DECIMAL(18,2) )  attr_rate
,   CAST(CAST((tot_orders - total_cancel) AS DECIMAL(18,2) ) / (tot_orders) * 100  AS DECIMAL(18,2) ) retn_rate
FROM (
    SELECT
        d.Enroll_Month
    ,   d.cncl_mnth
    ,   d.mth
    ,   s.tot_orders
    ,   d.tot_cancel
    ,   SUM(d.tot_cancel) OVER(PARTITION BY d.Enroll_Month ORDER BY mth ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) total_cancel
    FROM @summary s
    JOIN @Detail d ON s.Enroll_Month = d.Enroll_Month
) D
```

Comment: Thank you isR5!. Even after flipping the logic it is not displaying the accurate result set.

Comment: @PamPetronas I've updated my answer, and also put another approach without using cursor or CTE. (test the above cursor with the given sample, you'll get the same results) , but I highly recommend using the new approach (no CTE and cursor).